# ZF2 AbstractRestfulController Custom Methods

Tags: zend-framework2

How do I create custom methods? I understand when doing different HTTP calls such as POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, etc... but how do I create or use some custom methods aside from the main ones?

For example

get user by email?

Currently I can only get($id).. but what if I want both options? get by id, get by email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions for this.

You can send a http request with `GET`/query parameter for the user email to the collection path ('www.example.com/users'). This request should be handled inside the `AbstractRestfulController` its `getList` method and and then return a collection/array with the users that correspond to that email.

So your request for user with email `some_email@example.com` would look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/users?email=some_email%40example.com
```

You need to customize the getList action in a way that you can handle the query params.
Something in the controller like this:

```
$email = $this->params()->fromQuery('email');
```

Then you need to search in your database for users with that `$email` and then return them in an array or collection.

Another way would be to add a custom action to your controller:

```
public function myCustomAction(){
    -- SOME CUSTOM CODE --
}
```

and then in router you introduce a custom route and map it to that controller action like normally in ZF2:

```
'my_custom_route' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/my_custom_route',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'MyControllerWithCustomAction',
            'action'     => 'myCustomAction',
        ),
    ),
),
```

This means you add a custom route for finding users by email. Even though ZF2 allows you to do this it is not according to proper Restful practice.